# associated the list in the on pressed method

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgKH4.png)when i try to make an if statment in the on Pressed  an error occured which is => 'Equality operator '==' invocation with references of unrelated types[this is my code and in the text you will see my list i want to make an if statment in onPressed method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW0tf.png%60)

```
final List<Movie> movies = [
  Movie(

    imageUrl: 'assets/images/5s.PNG',
    title: 'video 1',
    categories: 'Fantasy, Sci-fi',
    year: 2018,
    country: 'uk',
    length: 60,
    description:
        'Our friendly neighborhood Super Hero decides to join his best friends Ned, MJ, and the rest of the gang on a European vacation. However, Peter\'s plan to leave super heroics behind for a few weeks are quickly scrapped when he begrudgingly agrees to help Nick Fury uncover the mystery of several elemental creature attacks, creating havoc across the continent.',
    screenshots: [
      'assets/images/1.PNG',
      'assets/images/2.PNG',
      'assets/images/3.PNG',
    ],
  ),
  Movie(
    imageUrl: 'assets/images/Star.PNG',
    title: 'Star',
    categories: 'Adventure, Family, Fantasy',
    year: 2000,
    country: 'US',
    length: 100,
    description:
        'All Clara wants is a key - a one-of-a-kind key that will unlock a box that holds a priceless gift from her late mother. A golden thread, presented to her at godfather Drosselmeyer\'s annual holiday party, leads her to the coveted key-which promptly disappears into a strange and mysterious parallel world. It\'s there that Clara encounters a soldier named Phillip, a gang of mice and the regents who preside over three Realms: Land of Snowflakes, Land of Flowers, and Land of Sweets. Clara and Phillip must brave the ominous Fourth Realm, home to the tyrant Mother Ginger, to retrieve Clara\'s key and hopefully return harmony to the unstable world.',
    screenshots: [
      'assets/images/l1.PNG',
      'assets/images/nl2.PNG',
      'assets/images/kl3.PNG',
    ],
  ),
  Movie(

    imageUrl: 'assets/images/johnyjohny.PNG',
    title: 'Johny',
    categories: 'Adventure, Fantasy',
    year: 2019,
    country: 'ire',
    length: 65,
    description:
        'Woody, Buzz Lightyear and the rest of the gang embark on a road trip with Bonnie and a new toy named Forky. The adventurous journey turns into an unexpected reunion as Woody\'s slight detour leads him to his long-lost friend Bo Peep. As Woody and Bo discuss the old days, they soon start to realize that they\'re two worlds apart when it comes to what they want from life as a toy.',
    screenshots: [
      'assets/images/johny.PNG',
      'assets/images/johny.PNG',
      'assets/images/johny.PNG',
    ],
  ),

];`
```

Comment: Hi @Jalenoss What is the **movies** and **movies[0]**

Comment: Please enter json ressponse of the API

Comment: the (movies) is a list and i wanna make an if statement inside the onPressed(){}

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you try to compare different types with each other; movies(List) and movies[0](a member of movies whose type is Movie) and they can not be equal never. For what reason you want to use "if" statement if you explain that, we may help you easier.

Comment: i have a main page, module page and the movie page ..... the module page has a final list as the one i shared with you above, the movie page has an Icon ; when the second movie is selected i the icon button to take me to other pah

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCbSZ.png)

[ [][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rAwy.png)

these are two images showing my code , i want when the user click on the arrow-play button to take him to other page where the video is displayed depending on the list of movies